# Delete blank rows from table

Tags: html, css, vue.js, for-loop, tr

```
<tr v-for="(value, key) in this.object" :key="key">
  <div v-if="value.item1 != null">
    <td width="400" class="alnleft">{{value.item1}}</td>
    <td width="50" class="alnright">{{value.item2}}</td>
  </div>
</tr>
```

With the v-if I am omitting values to print in tr. But above code printing black tr and unnecessary space is getting created . Please suggest how to get rid of this

Comment: could you provide code for ```this.object``` ?

Comment: its a dictionary

Comment: I solved it just by replacing tr with v-row –

Answer (score 0):

You dont ever want to place a `div` as the child of a `tr`. You can prevent the `div` from being inserted by replacing it with `template`.

```
<tr v-for="(value, key) in this.object" :key="key">
    <template v-if="value.item1 != null">
        <td width="400" class="alnleft">{{value.item1}}</td>
        <td width="50" class="alnright">{{value.item2}}</td>
    </template>
</tr>
```

Does that fix your issue?

Comment: No it doesn't worked

Comment: I solved it just by replacing tr with v-row